# How to consistently check localnotifications on watchkit vs the simulated remotenotification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, watchkit

I know it's been discussed that you cannot currently (as of xcode 6.3) test localnotifications pushing to the watch, but you can simulate remotenotification by using an .apns file and a dev scheme.

People say they are similar, so it seems like a good idea to use some kind of handling code to pass the data to do what you'd like. So for example in an apns with the following:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "bodyText",
            "title": "titleText"
        },
        "category": "myCategory"
    },
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [],    
    "customKey": "custom value."
}
```

I have an alert with "body" and "title" in it.

Now, to handle it in the watch's wkInterfaceController, i do the following

```
    override func didReceiveRemoteNotification(remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {
         if let remoteaps:NSDictionary = remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary{
              if let remotealert:NSDictionary = remoteaps["alert"] as? NSDictionary{
              handleNotification( remoteAlert );            
              }
         }
         completeHandler( .Custom )
    }

    func handleNotification( alert : AnyObject? ){

        if let alert = alert, let remotetitle = alert["title"] as? String{
            println( "didReceiveRemoteNotification::remoteNotification.alert \(remotetitle)" )
            titleLabel.setText(remotetitle);
        }
        if let alert = alert, let remotebody = alert["body"] as? String{
             //println( "didReceiveRemoteNotification::remoteNotification.alert \(remotetitle)" )
             bodyLabel.setText(remotebody);
        }
    }
```

Where the handling of the alert is abstracted, but how do I access that alert from localnotification's handler? Is that data in userInfo? somewhere else? Will this work?

```
override func didReceiveLocalNotification(localNotification: UILocalNotification, withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {
    handleNotification( localNotification.userInfo ); //is this the right way to pass this?

    completionHandler(.Custom)
}
```

Also, how do I send out that local notification to match that? Here is the phone side code to set up the notification:

```
    var reminderNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification();
    reminderNotification.category = "myCategory"
    reminderNotification.alertTitle = "TitleText"
    reminderNotification.alertBody = "BodyText"

    reminderNotification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60) //notify in one minute
    reminderNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminderNotification)
```

Comment: Running that code on actual hardware causes a segfault. It turns out the only thing one can write to in the notification is the user info object. That's probably what one should work with. I will try it and update

Comment: This last comment was wrong, you can also write to alertBody, but it will segfault if you try to write to alertTitle, as that seems to be just the name of the app

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler {
    // This method is called when a local notification needs to be presented.
    // Implement it if you use a dynamic notification interface.
    // Populate your dynamic notification interface as quickly as possible.

    NSString *reminderId = [localNotification.userInfo valueForKey:kAppLocalNotificationIdKey]; // This is a custom key
    [self manageNotification:@{@"title":localNotification.alertTitle,
                               @"body":localNotification.alertBody}
                      withId:reminderId];

    // After populating your dynamic notification interface call the completion block.
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}

- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler {
    // This method is called when a remote notification needs to be presented.
    // Implement it if you use a dynamic notification interface.
    // Populate your dynamic notification interface as quickly as possible.

    NSDictionary *aps = [remoteNotification valueForKey:@"aps"];
    if (!IsEmpty(aps)) {

        NSDictionary *alert = [aps valueForKey:@"alert"];
        if (!IsEmpty(alert)) {

            NSString *reminderId = [remoteNotification valueForKey:kAppLocalNotificationIdKey]; // This is a custom key
            [self manageNotification:alert withId:reminderId];

        }

    }

    // After populating your dynamic notification interface call the completion block.
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}

- (void) manageNotification:(NSDictionary *)notificationData withId:(NSString *)notificationId {

    NSString *title = [notificationData valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *message = [notificationData valueForKey:@"body"];

    [self.titleLabel setText:title];
    [self.messageLabel setText:message];

}
```

Comment: It might, but the project is a swift project.